# googlemaps url gets 404

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This has been working but today i noticed that when i try to access a googlemaps url via my site i get a 404 error.

my url:

```
 window.open("http://www.maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=" + start + "&daddr=" + globalWayPoints[0].location + "+" + "to:" + end + "&hl="+siteLanuguage+"&geocode=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=ls&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=47.167389,75.410156&ie=UTF8&z=7&layer=c&pw=2" + "&dirflg=t" + "&om=1" + "&z=1", "mywindow");
```

has something changed here?

EDIT:

FUll Url:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=split&daddr=55.37417,%2013.14731+to:47.000738,%2012.543741&hl=sv&geocode=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=ls&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=47.167389,75.410156&ie=UTF8&z=7&layer=c&pw=2&dirflg=t&om=1&z=1%22
```

Comment: can you show the full url (i.e. with the values from the variables)

Comment: check edits. the xxxxxxxxxxxx are for the api key which i would prefer not to share.

Comment: has anything changed on your site? switched to https:?

Comment: there have been updates such as features and bugfixes but i have not changed from http to https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `pw` paramter (`&pw=2`).

Remove `&pw=2` and the url works correctly.

FYI:

> “pw” stands for “print window.” It activates the print mode and
>   initiates printing. Example, pw=2.

Comment: Im kind of embarrassed to say but this did the trick. Wasted some time on this and did not even think that this could be causing the problem. Thanks for the help:

According to this: 
https://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

"pw=

Sets print mode."

Comment: although when i remove that parameter i now come to the googlemaps map instead of "print mode". That is not the desiered result, do you know of another paramater besides pw(doesn't work anymore obviosly) that can set the print mode?

Comment: this might be what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192696/how-to-view-google-maps-in-print-mode

Comment: ive seen that one. The thing is that it does not show the directionsOptions if i do that, it only prints the map